# I don't understand what's in my mysql query

Tags: mysql

i have query on mysql like this :

```
Select e.empno, e.ename, m.empno, m.ename as MANAGER
From scott.emp e, scott.emp m
Where e.mgr = m.empno (+);
```

what exactly is the function of the statement (+)

Comment: Are you talking about the literal `(+)`? That is not part of the query. Please [edit] your question to include more details on what you are talking about. Also explain where you get this `(+)` from.

Answer (score 1):

The `(+)` is a notation used by Oracle many years ago for an outer join. This syntax is specific to Oracle. It's not supported by MySQL or any other brand of SQL database. Even Oracle does not recommend using this syntax anymore, since they have supported standard OUTER JOIN syntax for years by now.

The correct syntax in MySQL is the following:

```
Select e.empno, e.ename, m.empno, m.ename as MANAGER
From scott.emp e
Left Outer Join scott.emp m
 On e.mgr = m.empno;
```

This will also work in Oracle since version 9i (circa 2001), and also every other brand of SQL database.